# Is there a way to trim Bezier curves in geometry nodes like Start and End mapping?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I know what you're thinking. "Duh it's the trim curve node"

Well... no. For some reason the handles for the bezier curve change with the trim and thus the curves themselves change shape as they are revealed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there someway to trim the curve without this effect?

Comment: Could you please share your blend file with us? ....Without it, it's hard to say, but you'd probably have to resample the curves somewhere.

Comment: @quellenform https://blend-exchange.com/b/WgxOXJke adjust the slider in Geometry nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you would simply have to process the curve with `Resample Curve` before the node `Trim Curve`. This will create points of a *Poly Line* at the required positions, which will then no longer be affected by the trimming.

[image]

The background to this is that you have previously created a Bezier curve that creates a new shape through individual handles. This shape must be "fixed" before you can trim the curve without changing the shape.